# What tables does the open cart 2.1.x.x utilizes when a new order is placed?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I am having to bypass the standard checkout process, the client wants something very custom.  I am at a spot where I need to insert the order into the mySQL database.  Please let me know which tables open cart 2.1.x.x utilizes when a new order is placed.

T.I.A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your database table prefix is `oc_`, `oc_order` is the table that stores orders information.
order's products are stored in `Oc_order_product` and if products have options, their options will be stored in `oc_order_option`.

Comment: This is what I came up with as well, I just wanted to be sure there were no other tables.  Thanks!